# If condition to give zeros after a number is repeated n times

Tags: r, if-statement

I have an XTS object of 20 columns with ones, negative ones and zeros.
I want to construct an if condition that gives zeros **after** negative ones or ones reaches a specific number count.
for example, if I have a data of 2 columns (variables) and I want to get zeros after 1 or -1 is repeated 15 times:

```
A<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)

B<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

data<-cbind(A,B)
```

I expect the result to be like data2

```
A2<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0)

B2<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

data2<-cbind(A2,B2)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am slightly confused by `A2` and `B2` based on your explanations. `A2` for example starts with `0` even though no values at that point has been repeated 15 times. In `A2` again, there is a `0` at index `17`; however, once again, no values have been repeated 15 times at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a traditional for-loop that works.

```r
library(dplyr)

to_zero <- function(var) {
  for (x in c(1, -1)) {
    state <- 0
    j <- 1
    for (i in seq_along(var)) {
      if (state == 0 & var[i] == x) 
      {
        j <- 1
        state <- 1
      }
      else if (state == 1 & var[i] == x & j < 15) j <- j + 1
      else if (state == 1 & var[i] == x & j >= 15) {
        var[i] <- 0
        j <- j + 1
      }
      else state <- 0
    }
  }
  return(var)
}

# Two columns
data %>% 
  mutate(
    A = to_zero(A),
    B = to_zero(B)
  )

# All columns
lapply(data, to_zero) %>% bind_cols()
```